# Eclipse Includes Header Files from Other Project

Tags: c, eclipse

I used Eclipse to compile a C project. But I find whenever I compile the project, it will not use the header files included in this project. Instead, it will includes the header file from another project. Is there any setting need to be changed? Thank you.

Comment: You using eclipse CDT builder for C project? That's kind of odd.. But if so, you have to change CPPFLAGS/CFLAGS in Preferences->C/C++ Build->Settings (as google suggests - don't use eclipse personally so can't check it out) and look for something like -Iyour/other/project/include/path

Comment: Thanks. I looked at the preference>C/C++ Build>Settings. I can see in the "Includes Tab", it includes a directory which contains the header files from another project. But the delete option of that directory is not available, do you know why?

Comment: Sorry i don't. But could you change it to point into your project directory?

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/206624/

ProjectA (with header files):
 Project Properties->C/C++ General->Export 
 Settings
 In tab Includes click "Add..." and then " Workspace..."
 Select ProjectA (or a subfolder).

ProjectB (with main.c):
 Project Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols
 in tab References select ProjectA